# How to test implementations of interfaces in Laravel

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, interface, phpunit

I have asked a specific question here:

[phpunit error when testing an implementation with injected dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876908/phpunit-error-when-testing-an-implementation-with-injected-dependencies)

However, I wonder whether the issue I am having is one of structure and design rather than coding. Therefore, I want to ask a more generic question here:

I'm using Laravel, I have written an interface and then a class that supports it. I have then used a service provider to bind the interface to the implementing class and inject the required dependencies which happens to be an Eloquent model.

My question is this: How should I go about testing this class? Currently I am calling a method on the interface. This therefore invokes the service provider to resolve the implementation (rather than the interface) and inject a model for me (which needs to be factory built or mocked). This feels I am testing too much (testing the service provider and the model, before even touching my target method). Should I be testing the implementation directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly - just test the implementation directly and bypass the IoC container altogether if you can.

Think about it like this - you code to an interface in part so that you can swap functionality out (say MySQL database driver for a PostgreSQl driver). As such, each individual implementation of a class must be tested. You should not rely on an IoC container binding to test a given implementation, as it's quite configuration-dependent.

As I see it, the only time you can rely on the IoC container to resolve things during testing is if the thing that gets resolved is a dependency of the thing you're testing and either:

- is itself fully tested so you know it works correctly
- performs expensive operations which you would prefer to not happen during testing (e.g. 3rd-party API operations or destructive things), in which case you should mock the class/interface and 'pretend' that it did the work and then returns something that you specify (also helpful in guaranteeing input and output of a depended-on component so you can test the class's responses to the dependency*)

Even then, you could manually inject dependencies to ensure a consistent code environment. The IoC container just helps to deeply create any dependencies without having to worry about it all in your tests.

---

*think about testing something that uses a 'now' date (and determines a person's age, say) without being able to specify, during testing, what to use as the 'now' date - you'd have to reimplement your age calculation code during testing just to work out the age in order to ensure that the code you wrote outputs the right age, which does very little to actually test your code!